# What can the differential operator map to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $W$ be the Weyl algebra $\mathbb{C}[x, \partial_x]$, that is the span of two elements $x, \partial_x$ with 
$$
\partial_x x -  x\partial_x = 1.
$$
If $\phi$ is a ring automorphism $\phi : W \to W $ with $\phi(x)= x$ what can $\phi(\partial_x)$ be?

So far I know that we must have 
$$
\phi(\partial_x) x - x \phi(\partial_x) = 1,
$$
and we can put a grading on $W$ by declaring the degree of $x$ to be $1$ and the degree of $\partial_x$ to be $-1$, so I thought a possibility might be
$$
\phi(\partial_x) = \partial_x^2 x,
$$
but this hasn't turned out to be true. Neither have similar looking elements like $x\partial_x^2$ or $\partial_x x \partial_x$. I'm looking for any other possibility other than just $\partial_x$, if such an element exists.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two equations imply that
$$
  (\phi(\partial_x)-\partial_x)x - x(\phi(\partial_x)-\partial_x) = 0,
$$
and so $\phi(\partial_x)-\partial_x$ commutes with $x$. Hence we can take $\phi(\partial_x) = p(x)+\partial_x$ for any polynomial $p$ and so get a
ring endomorphism. Since in this case the algebra generated by $x$ and $\phi(\partial_x)$ contains $\partial_x$, our endomorphism is an automorphism. It seems obvious that the only elements of the Weyl algebra that commute with $x$ are polynomials in $x$, and therefore we have all ring automorphisms that fix $x$.